# loading XML from string

Tags: php, xml

I try to load the XML from a string, but i get an empty object.

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    print_r($xml);
    foreach($xml->{'reference:item'} as $item){
        echo $item->{'resource:local-description'};
    }
}
?>
```

[$myXMLData and complete Code](http://pastebin.com/r9A43NLk)

The output is: "SimpleXMLElement Object ( )".
Why do I get no errors , but the Object is still empty?

Comment: Well, what does `$myXMLData` look like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r9A43NLk

Comment: As I explained in your previous question: 1) `print_r()` will not print your XML even on success 2) Your current syntax does not work because it's namespaced XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should read about parsing XML with namespaces. It is much differ from that with ordinary XML.

As first iteration, the `else` part of your code can be such:

```
} else 
    foreach($xml->children('reference', true) as $item)
        if($item->getName() == 'item') 
           foreach($item->children('resource', true) as $desc)     
              if($desc->getName() == 'local-description')
                  echo $desc ."\n";
```

[demo](https://eval.in/576495)

Answer (score 0):

It is working if you change your xml var to:

```
$myXMLData = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reference:reference
```

to

```
$myXMLData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reference:reference
```

It probably takes it as an empty far now

Comment: I use already the second one. With the first one I get this error: "Failed loading XML: 
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"